# Can't SetTexture() in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures

I'm trying to change texture in Unity on the fly. Do it exacty as described in the Official Documenation.
But nothing, not even an error nor notification happens.
There is Quad, Material applied to it and texture.png in folder

```
    private Renderer _renderer;
    [SerializeField] Material _materialToSet;
    [SerializeField] Texture _textureToSet;

    public void Start()
    {
        _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        //this works
        _renderer.material = _materialToSet;

        //this doesn't
        _renderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", _textureToSet);
    }
```

I just can't figure out what is the problem in. It all goes like fine, witn no errors nor warning, but texture stays the same. Maybe I shoud change texture type or something. Lost huge amount of time on this :(

Comment: Did you double check if the reference name of the Texture in this material is exactly `_MainTex` ?

Comment: OMG @pixlhero you are my hero! Thank you so much. I missed it thinking about _MainTex as a constant or smth.